# How to run the tangled file?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, microsoft-windows

How does one run the arbitrary command to execute the tangled code? I use Emacs both on Windows and Linux, but currently I need to run the generated batch file in particular Windows environment.
Here is how the block looks like:

```
#+begin_src bat :exports both :tangle "run_tests.bat"
...
#+end_src
```

I have a batch file which sets the environment (`d:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`), but cannot run my tangled file inside this new environment. How to do this?

The code can be tangled using `org-babel-tangle` of course, but I cannot run the generated batch file from Emacs using `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` as it says:

```
org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for bat!
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Tangling creates the batch file, execution of source block tries to execute the source block in the specified language (and there is no `ob-bat` I know of).

You can execute the tangled batch file in a shell source block. Therefore add the following to your org file:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results output
cmd /c ""d:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" & run_tests.bat"
#+END_SRC
```

This first runs the batch and then, separated by `&`, your batch script.

Note that I have a MinGW environment with a bash shell. If you want to run windows `cmd.exe` directly you may find a hint [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/org-babel-invoking-cmd-exe), which introduces a `shcmd` header option.

Also, you need to require `ob-sh` or `ob-shell`, depending on your org version. Therefore I do:

```el
(unless (require 'ob-sh nil 'noerror)
  (require 'ob-shell))
```

Btw, if all you want is to execute some command sequence you can simply do:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results output
call "d:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
echo "insert commands here"
#+END_SRC
```

**EDIT**:

Since I may need a windows native execution facility in org-mode I will write an `ob-bat.el` as soon as I am back from holiday (next week). Meanwhile you may try this code snippet (since I have no windows box it is untested):

```el
(require 'ob)
(require 'ob-shell)

(defvar org-babel-tangle-lang-exts)
(add-to-list 'org-babel-tangle-lang-exts '("bat" . "bat"))

(defcustom org-babel-bat-command "cmd.exe"
  "Name of command to use for executing bat code.")

(defun org-babel-execute:bat (body params)
  "Execute a block of bat code with cmd.exe.
This function is called by `org-babel-execute-src-block'."
  (let ((shell-file-name org-babel-bat-command))
    (org-babel-execute:shell body params)))

(provide 'ob-bat)
```

With this you should be able to execute bat source blocks:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC bat :exports results :results output
echo hello
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately the last block of code does not work. It is strange. In `*messages*` I see the following: `executing Sh code block...
Wrote c:/Users/alk/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-956097_/ob-input-9560CdR
Babel evaluation exited with code 1
Code block produced no output.`  And then in `*Org-Babel Error Output*` there is this following: `'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`  I can only imagine for you it works because you use MinGW.

Comment: Unfortunately currently I do not have a windows box around, so I can not verify that `sh` os used from `MinGW`. I suppose the command may as well come from GnuWin32 [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)... Btw this also give the opurtinity to install [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and [DiffUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm), which I highly recommend for increased usefulness of emacs on windows.