# After I updated Emacs 25.1 to 26.1 org-mode does not work any more

Tags: org-mode, emacs26

I am anything but an Emacs expert but I use Emacs `org-mode` quite frequently. I configured Emacs to regognize `.org` files. After I updated to version 26.1 Emacs does not only recognize `.org` files any longer:

```
File mode specification error: (file missing Cannot open load file No such file or directory ob-sh)
```

but can not even change to `org-mode`. `M-x org-mode` gives:

```
Cannot open load file No such file or directory ob-sh
```

I did not move my `.emacs` file or the `.emacs.d` folder.

Any idea?

Comment: After I moved my .emacs file and the .emacs.d folder to another location everything works fine. Still I would like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: FYI you didn't do anything wrong.  This was a breaking / backwards-incompatible change in org-mode, and I suspect that a lot of people upgrading to Emacs 26 have been (and will continue to be) tripped up by it.

Comment: Here's a tip, unrelated to your problem here: Instead of moving `.emacs` out of the way, just start up with `emacs --no-init-file` (on macOS: `open -a Emacs --args --no-init-file`) instead. (`--no-init-file` can be shortened to `-q`.) There is also a flag `--no-site-file` to stop the loading of site specific files.

Answer (score 20):

Emacs 26.1 comes with a much more recent version of org-mode than 25.1. `ob-sh` was renamed to `ob-shell` in org-mode 8.2, so you'll need to adjust whichever configuration in .emacs refers to `ob-sh`, as described in [ob-sh removal](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-07/msg00286.html):

> ** Incompatible changes
>
> *** `ob-sh.el` renamed to `ob-shell` This may require two changes in user config.
>
> 1. In `org-babel-do-load-languages`, change `(sh . t)` to `(shell . t)`.
> 2. Edit `local.mk` files to change the value of `BTEST_OB_LANGUAGES` to remove "sh" and include "shell".

You most likely need to search your config for a call to `org-babel-do-load-languages` and change `sh` to `shell` in the associated list of languages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I searched .emacs and .emacs.d for the string ob-sh but I couldn’t find it. Anyway I will restore my config step by step.

Comment: It could be 'sh' rather than 'ob-sh'. Bisecting your config should find the exact problem.

Comment: Also `emacs --debug-init` might pinpoint the line which is causing problems.

Comment: @MartinPetersen Look in your config for a call to `org-babel-do-load-languages` or setting the variable `org-babel-load-languages`.  You will need to change `sh` to `shell` in the associated list of languages.  If you might need to support *both* the old and new variants, let us know, as that can also be arranged.

Comment: Thanks to all of you I was able to solve the issue. Everything works now as intended. Again, thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. @MartinPetersen you should mark this as the correct answer

Comment: I just only followed your guide 1. ,my Emacs 26.2 didn't show error message anymore.